# Laravel Odoo API

Tags: laravel, rest, composer-php, odoo

I have been using Edujugon/laradoo for interfacing Laravel with Odoo. In a new project I have been using Laravel 9 and Edjugon/Laradoo does not install anymore.

Can somebody help me by updating Edjugon/Laradoo since the composer setting do not fit anymore with laravel 9. I am not enough of an expert to do that myself.  The goal is a successful composer require in Laravel 9.  I contacted the author but he seems to be not active anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I found a different solution: tbondois/odoo-ripcord. It is not as elegant as Edjugon/laradoo but it does the work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).